# Mongoose find record where array contains 2 elements that are provided

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

**SOLVED**

Hello everyone,
I have a collection in which there is 1 boolean and an array that contains two strings.
ex.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62148497fc3ac7c59252b53b"),
    "members" : [ 
        "61e4f988b92b443b29c87c38", 
        "61f0dd62e21a45de185854e9"
     ],
     "isGroup" : false,
     "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-02-22T06:37:11.406Z"),
     "updatedAt" : ISODate("2022-02-22T06:37:11.406Z"),
     "__v" : 0
}
```

**now I want to find records where that members array contains those two strings and also isGroup is false. I'm passing two strings that are in members from frontend.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search exact document which contains only these 2 values and the boolean, You can use the following code

```
db.collection.find({
    members:[
        "61e4f988b92b443b29c87c38",
        "61f0dd62e21a45de185854e9"
    ],
    isGroup: false
})
```

Instead, use the $all operator to locate an array that contains both the entries, regardless of order or other members in the array, Use the following code

```
db.collection.find({
    members:{$all:[
        "61e4f988b92b443b29c87c38",
        "61f0dd62e21a45de185854e9"
    ]},
    isGroup: false
})
```

Further readings [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#match-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/all/)

```
db.collection.find({
  members: {
    "$all": [
      "61e4f988b92b443b29c87c38",
      "61f0dd62e21a45de185854e9"
    ]
  },
  isGroup: false
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ga31UPDsjEu)